# Benefits from moving a field into local variable

Tags: java, android, performance

The code is like this

```
public class Universe {//abstract layer for life game

    public static final int SIZE = 100;
    private int[][] universe;
    private int[][] prev_universe;

    public Universe() {
        //Initializing Universe
        universe = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
        prev_universe = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
        initializeTiles();
    }//Universe()

//////
///various stuff
////

    public void doStep(){

        //backup the current state of the universe
        for(int i = 0; i < Universe.SIZE; i++) {
            prev_universe[i] = universe[i].clone();
        }


        //process data in "universe"




            //check if universe has changed
            if(deepEquals(universe, prev_universe)){
                    Log.d("CKdebug", "system is stable!");
                systemStable = true;
                }

        }

    }//class Universe
```

Everything works fine, but I'm curious about one thing. I don't really use `prev_universe` anywhere else but `doStep()`, to check if the state of the `universe` has changed. I think I can make it into a local variable.
The question is, will it be beneficial in terms of memory consumption and will it increase the load on the system (CPU, or something else) due to constant remaking of a large array `prev_universe` every time `doStep()` is called? What's the better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `prev_universe` is used only inside a single method, it should be private to that method. You won't gain much from pre-allocating a small array (100x100 is small).

By making `prev_universe` an instance variable, you run the risk of re-using it in other methods, which can lead to hard-to-track bugs (if the other method won't treat it as a local variable, and rely on its existing state, which will be reset each time `doStep()` is invoked).

Comment: +1, but it could be beneficial to pre-allocate it in certain cases. For example when calling that method many times or when `prev_universe` is used as a temporary object whose only purpose is to be overwritten and compared. Then it makes sense to allocate it once outside and use it over and over again (in a sensible manner).  
Classes like libgdx's [Vector3](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.peterlavalle/libgdx-degen.gdx.math/0.9.6/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector3.java) come to my mind, where temporary Vectors exist for keeping intermediate results.

Comment: @QBrute Such optimizations should only be done when you find that you have a performance problem, assuming you measure that those optimizations actually make a difference. They reduce the readability of your program and increase the risk of bugs, so they should be used with care.